# Timer error java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, timer

I'm trying to show a label to say that all is correct only for 3 seconds in JRE 8 because I can't use DatePicker in JRE 7 and I recive this error.

```
    Exception in thread "Timer-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Timer-2
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.addToDirtyList(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node.addToSceneDirtyList(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_markDirty(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node$7.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
at javafx.css.StyleableBooleanProperty.set(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at Pantallas.PersonalContabilidad$1.run(PersonalContabilidad.java:221)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

`correct` is a label and I show that 3 seconds and it fails at `correct.setVisible(false);` this is line 221

```
    correct.setVisible(true);
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
        correct.setVisible(false);
    }
    }, 3*1000);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The label correct should be updated from FX application thread. You should use `Platform.runLater()` here.

```
correct.setVisible(true);
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
@Override
    public void run() {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
          correct.setVisible(false);
      }
    });
}
}, 3*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because you call a Java FX GUI element not from the FX application thread. You can access GUI elements just from the GUI Thread. You could use [runLater(Runnable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html) to make sure that your code is executed within the right thread.